# generating UUID from dual table

Tags: java, hibernate, uuid

I want to generate UUID for a unique string, i am using the following code:-

```
thread.createSession();
HexGenerator gen1 = new HexGenerator();
gen1.setHexId("2");
thread.ses.save(gen1);
gen1 = (HexGenerator) thread.ses.load(HexGenerator.class, gen1.getHexId());
System.out.println("gen1-->" + gen1.getHexId());
thread.commit();
```

Below is my hibernate file:-

```
<class name="entity.HexGenerator" table="dual">
    <id name="hexId" type="string" unsaved-value="null">
        <generator class="uuid.hex"/>
    </id>
</class>
```

UUId is generated properly, but i am getting an error when the complete transaction is committed. as in the following error comes.

```
Exception in thread "main" - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at com.ofss.test.hibernate.HibernateThread.commit(HibernateThread.java:29)
    at com.ofss.test.hibernate.HibernateThread.main(HibernateThread.java:57)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00904: "HEXID": invalid identifier

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:343)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10698)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
    ... 9 more
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at com.ofss.test.hibernate.HibernateThread.commit(HibernateThread.java:29)
    at com.ofss.test.hibernate.HibernateThread.main(HibernateThread.java:57)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00904: "HEXID": invalid identifier

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:343)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10698)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't insert or update on the Oracle `dual` virtual table. You just can use it at `select` queries.
So, your line `thread.ses.save(gen1)` is what generates the error. I think that if you just delete this line, the error will be fixed.

But I don't really understand why you need to access the database to generate your UUID, which seems to be generated at the HexGenerator class (or maybe at the "uuid.gen" class referenced at the hibernate file).

Comment: i am using the above code to generate UUID, but is there any way to achieve the same???

Comment: Yes, there are some alternatives. You can check the UUID JDK class, http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html, which has some static methods to get one based on different algoritms

Comment: Or, you can create your own (not that hard, once you select the format your UUID will follow)

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the above problem, i mean to generate the UUID, now I have decided to use two method, either to use `java.util.UUID.randomUUID()` or to write my own logic to generate the same using bits array and then randomizing it.

Answer (score -1):

first, your code looks a little bit strange. You create instance of HexGenerator:

```
HexGenerator gen1 = new HexGenerator();
```

use it and immediately override using some unknown for me API that uses dynamic class loading.

```
thread.ses.load(HexGenerator.class, gen1.getHexId())
```

Then you call getHexId() again. I believe that code

```
new HexGenerator().getHexId()
```

will generate ID that you need.

But I think it is not yet the reason for failure. Unfortunately you did not provide any information about you DB schema. I believe that you ID is simply defined as number, it cannot accept strings. Check it again and please provide more details if this is not the reason.